# Is The Cabin in the Woods linked to the Buffyverse?

Tags: joss-whedon, the-cabin-in-the-woods, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

*The Cabin in the Woods* features a mysterious bureaucratic organisation that, although never named, commodifies certain supernatural creatures within its operation.

Both *Angel* and *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* also feature commercial businesses that participate in such activity, either in facilitation of them or in reaction to them: the former with [Wolfram & Hart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_&_Hart), the latter with [The Initiative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Initiative_%28Buffyverse%29) (of which Riley is an operative).

While others could also be argued, these two both have candidacy for potentially being connected to the un-named organisation within *The Cabin in The Woods*.

Given Whedon's current pursuits and (as evidenced by not only the Buffyverse, MCU and from [David Lavery's anecdotal evidence](http://www.bookdepository.com/book/9781848850309?redirected=true&viewCountry=UK&selectCurrency=GBP&gclid=CPuImsSuhL4CFScHwwodhI4AFg)) a propensity *toward* universe sharing, is there anything in *The Cabin in the Woods* that signals a crossover with another element of Joss Whedon's work?

Could they be diegetically linked?

Comment: Very cool question! I'll be interested to read others' answers!

Comment: Cracked.com recently explored something like this on "After Hours", where four writers from the site assume personas and pose crazy, convincing theories about movies and pop culture. (See: 8 Mind-Blowing Connections Between the Works of Joss Whedon ... http://www.cracked.com/video_18775_8-mind-blowing-connections-between-works-joss-whedon.html#ixzz30EfyjhTK )

Comment: Similar question present on Scifi and our mod asked it there  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/is-there-any-good-evidence-to-say-whether-the-cabin-in-the-woods-is-in-the-buffy

Comment: I really want to answer this question, but to be honest everything I would say is already contained in the answers in @AnkitSharma's link

Comment: @AndrewMartin but the answers present there are more based on comics then TV. You can come up with more TV series and Movie based explanation for this.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I can _try_ to, at least :P

Comment: IandotKelly noticed this 'duplication last night'; the Cracked.com video actually neatly circumvents all the arguments 'against' presented @SF&F, so even though it's been marked correct there is still room for discussion...

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"Similar question present on Scifi and our mod asked it there"* - What? Treason! ;-)

Comment: iso-cube prepped and ready for this treason!

Comment: Little Known Fact: The Doctor in the beginning of Serenity is an employee of Wolfram & Harte..... gotcha going, didn't I?

Comment: But all the supernatural events and monsters in CitWs are robots, smoke and mirrors, and science (excluding the sleeping old gods), correct? Or was just that one singular zombie an automaton?

While the monsters and magic in the Buffyverse are real.

So they could not be the same universe.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is just a coincidence of the same writer and some story elements which vaguely resemble each other. There's not a lot of research going on in CitW, while research and weaponizing is pretty much the MAIN goal for the Initiative.

Whedon denied this in an interview, because it would reveal him as less original, something which writers are keen to avoid.

I will get that link for you.

Comment: Please do get that link :)

Comment: OP never delivered said promised link. 